# iOS7 how to get current time and date based on specified timezone?

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

iOS Programming: I just want to let iOS7 get the "America/Chicago" current date and time.
I searched a lot on Internet, but there are a lot of different solutions. I tried several solutions, but they do not work.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Dates are timezone independent. It's only relevant when you wish to display a date to the user. Please better describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: @rmaddy - There are many real-world scenarios that would contradict that statement.  I think you meant that `NSDate` is time zone independent, not that dates in general are time zone independent. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson yes, I did mean NSDate. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the NSCalendar and NSTimezone classes.  The following code segment demonstrates retrieving the current hour and minute. Extending it to retrieve other date components is straight-forward -

```
long hour;
long minute;
NSCalendar *cal=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
NSTimeZone *tz=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Chicago"];

[cal setTimeZone:tz];
NSDateComponents *comp=[cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
hour=[comp hour];
min=[comp minute];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method,

```
- (NSDate *) getCountryDateWithTimeZone:(NSString *)zone
{

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeZone *szone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:zone];

    NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [szone secondsFromGMTForDate:now];
    NSTimeInterval interval = sourceGMTOffset;
    NSDate *destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:now];

    return destinationDate;
}
```

And,

```
[self getCountryDateWithTimeZone:@"America/Chicago"];
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe you also need to handle your (device's) timezone. You're calculating `secondsFromGMT`, not seconds from device's timezone.

Comment: Well, I am using it right now in my program.  for example if TimeZone is @"America/Chicago", [szone secondsFromGMTForDate:now]; return -18000 (-5 hour) and add to now date (now is not device timezone it's GMT time).

Comment: You're correct. I got misled by the formatting in `NSLog`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *firstDate = @"2014-06-05 12:55:00";

NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:firstDate];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:date toDate:currentDate options:0];

NSLog(@"The difference between from date and to date is %d days and %d hours and %d minute and %d second",components.day,components.hour,components.minute,components.second);
```

Output:

> DateBookApp[1179:70b] The difference between from date and to date is 0 days and 22 hours and 57 minute and 12 Second